# Obfuscate source code using ProGuard

Tags: java, android, serialization, obfuscation, proguard

Recently I've had some problems with people cheating using an app for root users called Gamecih. Gamecih let's users pause games and change variables in runtime.

If I obfuscate my code I though it'll be hard for cheaters to know what variables to change in runtime, but I'm also worried it might cause some other problems.

I serialize game objects using Javas Serializable interface and then write them out to a file. Now let's say I'm serializing an object of the class "Player". It gets serialized and saved to a file. Then a user downloads the update with the Proguard implementation. Proguard will rename classes and class member names. Won't that cause major errors when trying to read in an already saved Player object?

If I had not yet launched my game, this wouldn't be a problem. But now some players are playing on the same saved game(it's an RPG) for months. They would be pretty pissed off if they downloaded an update and had to start over from scratch.

I know I can instruct Proguard not to obfuscate certain classes, but it's the Player class I really need to obfuscate.

Clarification: Let's say I have the following simple *unobfuscated* class:

```
public class Player {

    private int gold;
    private String name;
    //Lots more.

    public Player(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getGold() {
        return gold;
    }
    public void setGold(int gold) {
        this.gold = gold;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

A player is created, serialized and saved to a file. After I implement obfuscator, it might look like this:

```
public class Axynasf {

    private int akdmakn;
    private String anxcmjna;

    public Axynasf(String adna)
    {
        anxcmjna=adna;
    }
    public int getAkdmakn() {
        return akdmakn;
    }
    public void setAkdmakn(int akdmakn) {
        this.akdmakn = akdmakn;
    }
    public String getAnxcmjna() {
        return anxcmjna;
    }
    public void setAnxcmjna(String anxcmjna) {
        this.anxcmjna = anxcmjna;
    }
}
```

Imagine that I post an update now and a player that has an unobfuscated version of Player downloads that update. When trying to read that Object there will be different member names and a different class name. I'll most likely get ClassCastException or something of the sorts.

Comment: Offtopic, but why? If some gamers want to play cheating let them, it is not as if they affect you or others.

Comment: @SJuan76: Because I have global highscore lists and pvp battles.

Comment: A little more deatil about the game would be helpfull. Also I don't understand exactly what you are doing on client side that could cause the problem?

Comment: @pst: Quoting myself: "I know I can instruct Proguard not to obfuscate certain classes, but it's the Player class I really need to obfuscate.". The goal is to prevent cheating and to do that, I need to obfuscate the entire Player class(that contains variables like gold, items, health etc.).

Comment: Just from the top of my mind (so probably is a bad idea) but why don't you use some sort of checksum or hash of the variables, adding a new class attribute to the Player class? If within the game the player get some gold then you update the gold and the checksum value. If the cheater just modify the gold and don't modify the checksum you know he is cheating.

Answer (score 1):

No expert in Proguard, but I think you're right to assume it is going to break serialisation.

One possible way of solving this might be to implement a layer over your current save structure - You can tell Proguard which classes you don't want to obfuscate. Leave the Player (and alike objects) the same for now and don't obfuscate. Once the object has been de-serialised, pass it up to your new layer (which is obfuscated) which the rest of the game deals with - if you don't retain the non-obfuscated object, then it'll cause cheaters problems tweaking during game play (although not at load time). At the same time, you could look at moving your player's game files over to another save option that doesn't depend on serialisation, which will probably make such issues easier in the future.

Comment: This should actually be quiet easy as you could extend player (as saved in the files) into obPlayer (an exact copy but obfuscated) - however doesn;t stop the players changing the data in the saved files

Answer (score 1):

For ensuring compatible serialization in ProGuard:

- ProGuard manual > Examples > [Processing serializable classes](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#serializable)

For upgrading a serialized class to a different class in Java:

- JDK documentation > Serialization > Object Input Classes > readResolve
- JDK documentation > Serialization > Object Serialization Examples > Evolution/Substitution

Comment: Please note that you should post the useful points of an answer here, on this site, or your post risks being deleted as ["Not an Answer"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259). You may still include the link if you wish, but only as a 'reference'. The answer should stand on its own without needing the link.

Answer (score 1):

I understand ppl can update vars @ runtime w/ the app you named.

If you change the member names, the values will still give hints.
If you obfuscate, the class name will change but new name will end on a forum anyway.
So this is not enough

What you could do in your update is, at startup, load serialized data in old object, transfer to "new" obfuscated class, use a custom serialization (with an XOR using the deviceID value or the gmail adress so to make it less obvious).

Try to have your player data into several classes too.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do in your situation:

1. Release an update with obfuscated and non-obfuscated class. When player gets loaded it will try with both classes. If player got loaded with non-obf. class then map this class to your obfuscated class.
2. When player gets saved it will save with obfuscated class.
3. After a proper amount of time release an update with only the obfuscated classes.